# how to read data from a MySQL server on (Mac Excel 2011 net.VB)?

Tags: mysql, excel

how to read data and send data from and too a MySQL server, with Mac Excel 2011 net.VB ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: nothing so far, I am quite new to vb :S

Comment: If you're new to VB, you should try searching for tutorials. SO is a question and answer forum, not a write-code-for-you forum. If you have tried something and it's not working, and you have a specific problem, please make a new post with that question.

Comment: Provide clear question, we are not wizards...

Comment: 1, sorry.
2, it's not easy to write code when you do not know what methods exist on mac vb and when you do not know what mac vb can handle. 
3, I can write php, c #, c++, Java, javascrip and so on (I'm not an expert!).

Comment: While I agree with Ryan but we all have to start somewhere. and stack overflow is where all the experts are! That being said I googled a code example for you on how to connect to mysql via vba using odbc (and read data)In the future, you should always try googling before stackoverflow because if your question shows little effort, or was obvious with a google you are opt to get comment like the ones above. Even I've posted a `dumb` question on stack that I COULD have googled, but wasnt able to find the answer to. (see my profile, it's my first question on the site) Wishing you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: http://bit.ly/Qfqvwb

1. install the 3.5.1 odbc driver from mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html (easy click click)
2. setup an ODBC connection

   ```
   Private Sub btnTestReadInMysqlData_Click()

   Dim objDB, arrRecord, strRecord, strOutput
   Dim oRS, nRec, oFld
   Dim row

   'Database connection & select all from Table
   Set objDB = DBConnect()
   Set oRS = objDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM members")

   'Dump Records from Table
   nRec = 0
   row = 1
   Do While Not oRS.EOF
     For Each oFld In oRS.Fields

       'WScript.Echo oFld.Name & " = " & oFld.Value

       Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(row, 1).Value = oFld.Value

       'increment
       row = row + 1

     Next
     oRS.MoveNext
   Loop

   End Sub


   Function DBConnect()
   Set objDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   objDB.Open "websitedata"
   Set DBConnect = objDB
   End Function
   ```